# facebook like button not displaying news article content

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, blogs

I'm implementing a facebook like button on a simple blog/news section I created in an MVC 3 web application.

I used the XFBML way to implement this.

It works, but not completely.
When clicking and checking it on facebook, it shows the title I specified.

Here is a piece of code.
The viewbag information comes from my view, this is in the layout/master page.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="@ViewBag.FGTitle" />
```

But since it's a news item, I also want the content of the article to be displayed.
It only shows, the title, the site name and that's it.

I checked the facebook developer page, but I cant find a meta property/Open graph type in which i can set this content.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the [facebook url linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) it shows you exactly what facebook sees when greping the url. Also you should read up on the [other meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Comment: Thanks for the links Rufinus. This `<meta property="og:description"
          content="@ViewBag.FGContent"/>` meta tag is not on the main facebook like button page [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). For some weird reason it didn't cross my mind to keep on searching the site for other possible meta tags that could be used. It works perfectly now. I'm also gonna check out that url linter thing, I was not aware of such a tool.